# I am trying to count the store position of spaces in an array. But it always prints 0 as a position of space too, why?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, e[10000];
    char d[10000];
    printf("Enter text: ");
    gets(d);

    while(d[a] != '\0')
    {
        if(d[a] != ' ')
        {
            b++;
        }
        else
        {
             e[c]=a;
             c++;
        }
        
       
        

        a++;
    }

    printf("Number of characters without spaces: %d\n", b);
    for(int i=0; i<=c; i++)
       printf("Spaces : %d \n", e[i] );
    getch();

}
```

Every time I run the program, the output for spaces comes out to be the position of spaces, as expected, and then at the last, space: 0. if I change the condition in the for loop from i<=c to i<c, the problem is solved. That leads me to the conclusion that e[c]=0. I don't why the last value in e would be 0, can anyone explain?

Comment: `printf("Spaces : %d", e);` is incorrect as the compiler should tell you. `e[]` is an array which decays to a pointer when passed to `printf`. Did you mean `printf("Spaces : %d", c);`? Or did you mean to print the elements of `e[]` in a loop?

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean to print them in a loop, sorry, my mistake. I am only starting to understand c.

Comment: That's why you get the strange output: it might be the lowest 32 bits of a pointer value, but the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: You should never ever use `gets` in any program. It is considered dangerous and was deprecated and even removed from C standard decades ago. Use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First this code won't compile, because you have too many closing brackets.

Second you are trying to print the array e directly, which results in printing the memory address instead of the actual elements. You should loop through the array and print the elements one by one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
  printf("%d ", e[i]);
}
```

Comment: I understood the loop thing, but not the bit about closing brackets, it does compile and run perfectly. I still have the question tho, why does it only print that specific number?